# Unable to view the version history of workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I am unable to view the previous versions of the workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013. I have tried to reset the IIS but it didn't work and it always says as "Server is busy" and never shows any history. Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? I'm experiencing the same problem.